# Pygame move a object to mouse

Tags: python, pygame, mouse

I wanted to move a sprite (bullet) slowly to the coordinates of the mouse by calculating the x and y of the image with:

```
angle = math.atan2(dX,dY) * 180/math.pi
x = speed * sin(angle)
y = speed * cos(angle)
```

The problem is that even though a sprite points to the mouse (in this game, the gun) with the same angle (using pygame.transform.rotate) the bullet still moves to incorrect coordinates.

**Current Code Example:**

```
dX = MouseX - StartpointX
dY = Mouse_Y - StartPointY
Angle = ( math.atan2(dX,dY) * 180/math.pi ) + 180
Bullet_X =Bullet_X + Speed * math.sin(Angle)
Bullet_Y = Bullet_Y + Speed * math.cos(Angle)
```

How do I solve this?

[An example to show it clearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4JLL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There are three things wrong with your calculations.

1. `math.atan2` takes the arguments in the order y and x, not x and y. This isn't a huge deal since you can compensate for it.
2. `math.cos` and `math.sin` takes **radians** as arguments. You have converted the angle to *degrees*.
3. *Cosine* represent the x-value while *sine* represent the y-value.

So the calculations should be something like this:

```
dx = mouse_x - x
dy = mouse_y - y
angle = math.atan2(dy, dx)
bullet_x += speed * math.cos(angle)
bullet_y += speed * math.sin(angle)
```

### Short example using the solution

```
import pygame
import math
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x, y, dx, dy = 360, 240, 0, 0
player = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
player.fill((255, 0, 255))

bullet_x, bullet_y = 360, 240
speed = 10
bullet = pygame.Surface((16, 16))
bullet.fill((0, 255, 255))


def update(mouse_x, mouse_y):
    global x, y, dx, dy, bullet_x, bullet_y
    dx = mouse_x - x
    dy = mouse_y - y
    angle = math.atan2(dy, dx)
    bullet_x += speed * math.cos(angle)
    bullet_y += speed * math.sin(angle)

run_update = False
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            raise SystemExit
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                run_update = True
                mouse_x, moues_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if run_update:
        update(mouse_x, moues_y)
        if 0 > bullet_x or bullet_x > 800 or 0 > bullet_y or bullet_y > 800:
            bullet_x, bullet_y = 360, 240
            run_update = False
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(player, (x, y))
    screen.blit(bullet, (bullet_x, bullet_y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I ran the example code above. The object doesn't move when the mouse is clicked. What's wrong?

Comment: @NuhYamin When you have a programming problem, try to be as specific as you can, as many things can go wrong. This code is far from perfect, but demonstrates the principles of how the algorithm works. When I run the program, the bullet moves when clicked. Do you get any errors? Does the program display the bullet and the player? Do you have pygame installed and are you using Python 3?

Comment: Sorry, it works now. I don't know why at the time of asking it didn't work. I didn't change anything in the code but now it works. Thanks for sharing.